# DoesNotExist at /blog/postComment Post matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print the comments below the blog but after clicking the submit button the above error shows up. I just want a success message to be displayed on the top of the web page, for which I have written the line: `messages.success(request, 'your comment has been added')`, but the error shows up!

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " by " + self.author


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('postComment', views.postComment, name='postComment'),
    path('', views.blogHome, name='home'),
    path('<str:slug>', views.blogPost, name='blogpost'),
]
```

**view.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from blog.models import Post, BlogComment


def blogHome(request):
    allpost = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'allposts': allpost}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogHome.html', context)


def blogPost(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    comments = BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {'post': post, 'comments': comments}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogPost.html', context)
    


def postComment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        user = request.user
        postSno = request.POST.get("postSno")
        post = Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)

        comment = BlogComment(comment=comments, user=user, post=post)
        comment.save()
        messages.success(request, 'your comment has been added')

        return redirect(f"/blog/{post.slug}")

    return redirect('home')
```

**blogPost.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
{{ post.title}}
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron my-4">
    <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">{{post.timeStamp}} by <a href="#">{{post.author}}</a></p>

        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
      <form action="/blog/postComment" method = 'post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name = 'comment' placeholder = 'type here'>
        <input type="hidden" name = "comment" value = "{{post.sno}}">
        <input type="submit" value = 'submit'>
      </form>
    <div class="row my-2">
      <div class="col-md-2">image here</div>
      <div class="col-md-10">comments here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

**error log**:

```
DoesNotExist at /blog/postComment
Post matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/postComment
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Post matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Users\jayant nigam\projects\practise\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 429, in get
Python Executable:  C:\Users\jayant nigam\projects\practise\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\jayant nigam\\projects\\everythingcs',
 'C:\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\jayant nigam\\projects\\practise',
 'C:\\Users\\jayant nigam\\projects\\practise\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 02 Oct 2020 19:21:31 +0000
```

I don't know why this error is showing up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in template. You setted wrong `name` to one of your inputs:

In your code:

```py
<input type="hidden" name = "comment" value = "{{post.sno}}">
```

Right version:

```py
<input type="hidden" name = "postSno" value = "{{post.sno}}">
```

Comment: not working for me! new error shows up ```NameError at /blog/postComment
name 'comments' is not defined```

Answer (score 0):

In case to solve your first problem you should change the line `post = Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)` (in the `postComment` function) to something like:

```
from django.http import Http404

try:
    post = Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    return Http404("Post does not exist") # or return HttpResponse("Post does not exist")
```

because there might be situations that this query can not return any result and therefore it will raise `DoesNotExistError`. The second problem (I mean `NameError at /blog/postComment name 'comments' is not defined`) comes from the same function... changing this line `comment = BlogComment(comment=comments, user=user, post=post)` to `comment = BlogComment(comment=comment or '', user=user, post=post)` will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change comments to comment as "comments" is not defined. You are using comment.